# YouTube Android Player API how to enable captions?

Tags: java, android, android-youtube-api

I have a little android app that uses the YouTube Android Player API
for playing youtube videos and I would like to enable the captions from the youtube video. I don't see anything in the api that could help me achieve this. Even with close captioning enabled in  system settings the captions are not displayed.Is it possible to display the captions?

Answer (score 0):

Just enable them in Youtube Player within your app, by pressing the `CC` button.